# How to Install/Copy all constraints of on size class to the other in IOS 8 Autolayout

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, autolayout, landscape

I am doing Autolayout for my views and I am have installed constraints for **Compact Width, Compact Height** It is working fine for iphone 5,6, 6+ but in iphone 4 it is not working and i think i have to do any **Width, Compact Height.** Now I just want to copy all the constraints from **Compact Width, Compact Height**  TO **Width, Compact Height.** How can I do this because I have so many Views and going on each view seems very tedious..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just noticed my question is still unanswered so here's how I add already installed constraints to other size classes

Step 1: Select all constraints you want to apply to another size class in documents outline

[image]

Step 2: If you want to apply it all just ✓ check the installed checkbox. Otherwise tap **+** button just on the left side shown in red rectangle in below image and choose your target size class. **Mark it Checked ✓ ** Yes You have done it ^_^

[image]

**PS: Remember the x button will delete the constraints so you can also remove the constraints from any class you want**